# Implementing sub string % search for postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got a postgres DB with a sequence table that has columns like so

| id | name | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191212 | seq1 | gtagagctttttttgatgttctatcatcttgggggggaaa |
| 414124 | seq2 | cccggtttaatatttggttttttgggagggagagagagggggggagag |

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way of doing an efficient sub string search on this table which would also allow for fuzzy matching.

For example the following searches only looking for >80% matches would produce the following results:

| search seq | matches on seq | match index start | % match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcttgggggggaaa | seq1 | 26 | 100% |
| tcttgggggggaaat | seq1 | 26 | 93% |
| tcttgggggtggaaa | seq1 | 26 | 93% |
| tcttggggggaaa | seq1 | 26 | 92% |
| ttttttt | seq1 | 7 | 100% |
| ttttttt | seq2 | 17 | 85% |

I'm defining

```
% match = (number of exact letter matches) / (length of search seq)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fuzzy matching is not efficient. And your idea of "fuzzy" doesn't lend itself to regular fuzzy approaches.

Comment: I'm not sure about your use case, but assuming those sequences are huge, this looks like a purpose-built bioinformatics [sequence database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_database) will be the way to go

Comment: can you give us a formal definition of your %-match metric?  Your examples don't show any internal mismatches, or head mismatches, leaving it pretty vague about what it means.

Comment: @jjanes I've updated the question to include my definition of the %-match metric and added a couple examples

Comment: [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/pgtrgm.html) has several options for similarity, though not exactly as you have it.